# Connecting to SMTP server through PHP fails

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I have a website which I have programmed one of its pages to connect to SMTP to send clients an email. The issue starts when I upload the files to host, which then it won't connect and show me an error `SMTP Error: Connection timed out`.

On localhost, the code works fine and connects successfully in an instance. Is there something I need to change in the code or in the host settings to make it work fine?

Using PHPMailer, these are my connection variables (excluding subject, body etc):

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->AuthType = 'LOGIN';
$mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
$mail->SMTPOptions = array( 'ssl' => array( 'verify_peer' => false ) );
```

Comment: Does your "host" allow external connections to originate from their servers and go out to some other servers?  Some do not allow that.  Your host provider might have an SMTP server you are allowed to connect to that is internal to them.

Comment: @Nic3500 I tried connecting to their own SMTP server as well, same issue. I contacted them and they said no problems from their side..

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Comment: The OP stated he uses PHPmailer already, it a connectivity issue, not a libraby issue IMHO.

Comment: Yes, I'm already using PHPMailer which works fine on localhost, but on my purchased host it does not. The connection times out.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue starts when I upload the files to host

Why do you think that uploading files influencing the connectivity to the mail server?

> $mail->SMTPOptions = array( 'ssl' => array( 'verify_peer' => false ) );

That's not a good idea.

> Is there something I need to change in the code or in the host settings to make it work fine?

If you change something in the code, in the host settings or in the network infrastructure where the host resides then it will probably start working (see note 1) but because you've only told us about (some of) the code, we cannot guess what that might be.

Its not uncommon for an internet facing host to be constrained in what it can do - this can be restricted by routing, firewalls, DNS availability & permissions. These are the things you should be checking (or speaking to the people whom manage the host).

note 1: for the benefit of later readers - you may also need to change *something* at the mail server too - but that probably doesn't apply here if the code behaves as expected when running on a different host)

Answer (score 0):

You are having `Connection timeout` issue. That is most possibly because of something wrong in your configuration which is preventing your code to connect with google smtp server.

**First of all** make sure you are using the latest version of PHPMailer. Going further with your code that is having issue

Please follow the following update to debug and resolve the issue

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication;
$mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to`
```

<del>`$mail->AuthType = 'LOGIN'
$mail->SMTPOptions = array( 'ssl' => array( 'verify_peer' => false ) );`</del>

I believe you should get a positive result if you try with the edited code chunk.

For further clarity on this, you might like to have a look at their (PHPMailer's) actual doc to [connect with Google SMTP](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps)

Hope, this helps!